# Wierd constructor behavior

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I have a problem with the constructor of a model I have. I use Laravel-3 with Eloquent ORM.

***Here's the behavior I would expect :***

```
Class A{
    $dat_var = 1;
    public function __construct{
        $this->dat_var = 2;
    }
}

Class B extends A{
    public function __construct{
        echo 'before : '.$var;
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'after: '.$var;
    }
}

Class Test{
    public function myTestMethod2(){
        $b = new B();
    }
}
```

Result of myTestMethod1() :

```
before : 1
after : 2
```

But with my Laravel object which extends Eloquent, the variable is unsetted until the object has finished constructing. I guess this have something to do with the fact that the variable I need in my Eloquent model is loaded from the DB. But anyway, **is there any elegant work-around for this** or **am I doing something wrong**?

***Here's my DB table :***

```
--------------
-table_c     -
--------------
-id  | my_var-
--------------
-1   | 5     -
--------------
```

***Here's my laravel code :***

```
Class C extends Eloquent{
    public static $table = 'table_c';

    public function __construct{
        //Usefull things here
        parent::__construct();
        echo 'In construct : '.$this->my_var;
    }
}

Class Test{
    public function myTestMethod2(){
        $c = C::find('1');
        echo 'Construct finish : '.$c->my_var
    }
}
```

Result of myTestMethod2() :

```
In construct :
Construct finish : 5
```

What I expected of myTestMethod2() :

```
In construct : 5
Construct finish : 5
```

Comment: Is this your real code? There's a lot of stuff missing: D::_constuct(), declaration of $my_var on C...

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro no, its not my real code, i simplified it to expose the problem more clearly. I dont need to declare $my_var on C because Eloquent (laravel's ORM) will set it for me since it is a variable from the table of C. I will try to make it a bit more clear. Thanks you for feed-back.

Comment: There's nothing unexpected happening here -- it's not going to have a value until it is assigned. What are you trying to do that you require the property to have a value before/after the constructor is fired?

Comment: @Cryode After the constructor is fired, i need to initialize an internal object based on my_var value and i would like it to be auto initialized after the constructor has been fired without having to call another method on my object.